# Reading from .txt file, only reading certain documents?

Tags: java, string, file, text

I'm trying to load a .txt file with multiple strings but the loader is choosing to only output certain files (I'm testing with two- although they're both just strings- but I think the fact that the second filee includes capitals may be causing problems?). **The first text file is outputting perfectly.** I've made sure to put the file size reader, but it's not making a difference:

```
    this.inputString = new Lab3Q2 [size]; // create arrays
    this.outputString = new String [size];
```

The error message on the console reads:
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
        at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
        at Lab3Q2.processStrings(Lab3Q2.java:80)
        at Lab3Q2Loader.loadFile(Lab3Q2Loader.java:60)
        at Lab3Q2Loader.main(Lab3Q2Loader.java:77)

The first .txt file reads:

```
2
how are you today
i am doing well
```

The second .txt file reads:

```
5
The king looked; well
The cook worked long hours in the darkened kitchen
Well, I think this king is crazied 88
All 2567 kings liked the king of ID.
The cooled computer room at DSSS is used for computers.
```

This is the code for the loader (Please excuse the poor comments):

```
// The "IDSpeakLoader" class.
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Lab3Q2Loader
{

    // private data for input and output strings
    private Lab3Q2 inputString[];
    private String outputString[];


    //Creates a new instance of <code>IDSpeakLoader</code>.

    public Lab3Q2Loader ()
    {
        this.inputString = null;
        this.outputString = null;
    }


    //method to get the private output data
    public String[] getOutputString ()
    {
        return this.outputString;
    }


    //method to load the file and send it to Lab3Q2 fo processing
    public void loadFile () throws IOException
    {

        FileReader fr = new FileReader ("String.txt"); // file must be with class file in
        BufferedReader inputFile = new BufferedReader (fr);

        int size = Integer.parseInt (inputFile.readLine ()); // read size

        this.inputString = new Lab3Q2 [size]; // create arrays
        this.outputString = new String [size];

        for (int i = 0 ; i < inputString.length ; i++)
        {

            String string1;

            string1 = inputFile.readLine ();

            // Create an array of Lab3Q2 objects
            this.inputString [i] = new Lab3Q2 ();

            // call methods in each of those objects to save and process the strings
            this.inputString [i].setInputStrings (string1);
            this.outputString [i] = this.inputString [i].processStrings ().toUpperCase (); //process and save

        }

        inputFile.close (); // close the file
    }


    //@param args the command line arguments

    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {

        // create an object of the loader
        Lab3Q2Loader strL = new Lab3Q2Loader ();

        // load the file
        strL.loadFile ();

        String output = ""; // string to hold ouput information

        // get the information from loader
        for (int i = 0 ; i < strL.getOutputString ().length ; i++)
        {
            output = output + strL.getOutputString () [i] + "\n"; // add info for each element to
        } // output + a new line

        JTextArea text = new JTextArea (); // set a text area to display
        text.setText (output);

        //display the information
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, text);

    } // main method
} // class
```

The Loader is named "Lab3Q2Loader" and the class is called "Lab3Q2"

Comment: What's `Lab3Q2.processStrings(Lab3Q2.java:80)` or just `Lab3Q2.processStrings()` look like.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to be specific without seeing the source for Lab3Q2, but you are most likely doing a `String.indexOf` to find a substring that does not exist in the main string, causing `indexOf` to return -1.  Then you are feeding that index into `String.substring`, causing your StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.